# Fields added to um-registration form is not shown in database

Tags: user-registration

Hi guys I am using evolve theme and installed Ultimate member plugin for users registration. But now facing two problems. As per documentation I added a new field  with name'Portal Name' to the registration form. But no field has been added to the database's table (wp_users). What should I do? How can I be able to add a new field and input data to this field along with others?
Besides, when I add fields to the Profile form, that too shows nothing.

Also want to get suggestion a name of plugin which allows to add custom fields and give an option for uploading profile image without complicacy.

Comment: Nobody answered my question. Is not it a valid question?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed **Ultimate Member** does store these values in `usermeta`, they are stored in `meta_key` and `meta_value` fields.

For instance, if you have added a custom field to a form and called it as `my_custom_field`, the data written in there at registration step will be stored in `usermeta` table in your database as

```
meta_key = 'my_custom_field', meta_value = 'whatever'
```

You can retrieve these values like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$query  = "SELECT `meta_value` FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'my_custom_field' AND `user_id` =  '$uid'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($query, 2));
return $results[0]->meta_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress's `wp_users` table is fixed. And no plugins can add more fields to it.

Instead, adding custom fields to a registration form *might* add these fields to `wp_usermeta` table. I'm not sure if Ultimate member plugin can do that. But you can create registration form with custom fields using the [MB User Profile](https://metabox.io/plugins/mb-user-profile/) plugin. It allows you to create forms for registration, editing profile and you can add 40+ custom field types to the forms.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware that the wp_users is fixed. I manually created a new field in it. But it does not take input from the Ultimate member plugin. Anyway thanks for the suggestion of the new plugin. I will try it.